# Android OS closing flutter app due to low memory

Tags: android, flutter

I have a flutter app that seems to be closed by the android operating system. It will be running fine for three or more hours, then my screen will return to the android home screen.

When I look into the logcat, all I can see is a low memory warning.

Has anyone seen this with flutter applications? Is there a way I can prevent my flutter application from being closed by the OS?

Thanks

Comment: This happens to all apps.  If its not in the foreground, the OS has the right to kill it for memory.  If it is in the foreground, the OS won't kill it for memory unless the OS is out of memory to give it.

Assuming you're talking about a foreground app, I'd be looking for memory leaks and heap profiling for them.

Comment: Please note that the Android OS has several buckets of memory.  If the correct bucket doesn't have enough room, the allocation fails.  Of particular interest is generally the Java heap, which will have OEM specific maximum sizes.  Once its gone, you won't be able to claim more even if the OS has free RAM.